# How do I pass a promise result into a variable in Next.js getStaticProps()?

Tags: javascript, next.js, es6-promise

I'm trying to pass the `article` props in Next.js using getStaticProps(). However, this code returns an error because `article` is an `[object Promise]`.

```
 const getArticles = (uid) =>
    client
      .query(Prismic.Predicates.at('my.article.categories.category', uid), {
        orderings: '[my.article.date_written desc]',
      })
      .then((res) => res.results);
  const articles = getArticles(params.uid);
```

How do I set `articles` as `res.results`?

Comment: in an `async` function, `const articles = await getArticles(params.uid);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick answer would be something like this:

```
const articles = await client
  .query(Prismic.Predicates.at('my.article.categories.category', params.uid), {
    orderings: '[my.article.date_written desc]',
  });
```

If you need a more precise answer in case this is not appropriate, you can share more code.